# Setting the response content-type without using HttpServletResponse

Tags: spring-mvc, content-type

How can I get `HttpServletResponse object` in a method in my spring controller **so that my application remains loosely coupled with Http API?**

Thanks...

Edit: Actually what i want is to set the *ContentType* of the HttpServletResponse object in my controller.Does spring provides any way for this without getting HttpServletResponse object as argument in the method of controller?

Answer (score 12):

I can see two options:

If the content-type that you want is static, then you can add it to `@RequestMapping`, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="...", produces="text/plain")
```

This will only work if the HTTP request contains the same content-type in its `Accept` header, though. See [16.3.2.5 Producible Media Types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces).

Alternatively, use `ResponseEntity`, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/something")
public ResponseEntity<String> handle() {
  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "plain"));
  return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

`MediaType` also has a handful of common mime types defined as constants, e.g. `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`.

See [16.3.3.6 Using `HttpEntity<?>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity)

Comment: the line `responseHeaders.setContentType("text/plain");
` in above code gives error : `setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType) in org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)`.  SO i tried : `responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("text/plain"));` But that gives error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token character '/' in token "text/plain"`. Any suggestion?

Comment: skaffman: I have run your edited code, it is now giving error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.readOnlyHttpHeaders(Lorg/springframework/http/HttpHeaders;)Lorg/springframework/http/HttpHeaders;
 org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.<init>(HttpEntity.java:100)
 org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.<init>(HttpEntity.java:70)
 org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.<clinit>(HttpEntity.java:58)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass it as an argument, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping( value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void test( HttpServletResponse response ) { ... }
```

Comment: But this will bind my controller to Http API which i do not want.Please see my edit also.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is to use a specific [View-Implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html), since here to response-rendering should take place.