# using ResponseEntity<t>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This question is in reference of the question:

[Setting the response content-type without using HttpServletResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928075/setting-the-response-content-type-without-using-httpservletresponse)

with the following code:

```
@RequestMapping("handle.htm")
        public ResponseEntity<String> handle() {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "plain"));
        //responseHeaders.set("myheader","xyz");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
```

I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.readOnlyHttpHeaders(Lorg/springframework/http/HttpHeaders;)Lorg/springframework/http/HttpHeaders;
    org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.<init>(HttpEntity.java:100)
    org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.<init>(HttpEntity.java:70)
    org.springframework.http.HttpEntity.<clinit>(HttpEntity.java:58)
    ...
```

But in spring API docs there is a static method:

```
static HttpHeaders  readOnlyHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders headers)
```

Then why it is giving such error?

Thanks...

Comment: Which version of spring-web.jar are you using?

Comment: @ralph: I am using _spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar_.

Comment: I have had a look in the code, and it must work. Double check everything that you do not use different (old) versions of that jar. Also double check that you use `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders` but not `org.commons.shomehting.HttpHeaders`

Comment: @Ralph: I have upgraded my pom.xml to use version 3.0.6.RELEASE for all Spring dependencies defined there and IT WORKED.Thanks...

Comment: I have reposted my comment as answer, so you can finish the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look in the code, and it must work. Double check everything that you do not use different (old) versions of that jar.